# youtube RSS feed for playlist not working

Tags: .net, rss, youtube-api

I am using youtube RSS feed in application to retrieve videos from playlist.
The feed was working as expected. But before few weeks it was stopped working.

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/Playlist_ID

Can anyone aware about this issue. Has the api feed syntax changed for the youtube playlist.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: define not working are you seeing an error?  Could you post a link that is not working so we can see the error.

Comment: Think this is a v2 API call which has now been deprecated. You will need to upgrade to v3 equivalent. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list

Answer (score 1):

Have you try something like that ?

https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?playlist_id=Playlist_ID